# python 3 summing numbers from input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a program that takes a number and sums it
But for some reason the code wont work

```
number = input("please enter a four digit number: ")
final = sum(number)
print(final)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

I've attempted to convert it into a integer and string but it keeps saying that each of them is irritable

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`input` returns a string. So you have to convert each char to an integer before you can sum them

```
>>> number = '1234'
>>> final = sum(map(int, number))
>>> print(final)
10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.

```
def sumNumber():
    number = input("please enter a four digit number: ")
    return sum(int(x) for x in number)

print(sumNumber())

#   Examples:
#   22222 returns 10
#   12345 returns 15
```

This function converts the string input into a list of integers, then returns the sum of the array using `sum()`.

Answer (score 0):

OR:

```
number = input("please enter a four digit number: ")
final = sum(int(i) for i in number)
print(final)
```

Ex output:

```
please enter a four digit number:  1234
10
```